# Get Length Of Json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have json object which is returned from php file, the json values are as follows

```
    {
  "0": {
    "id": "35",
    "name": "first name",
    "date": "2014-03-03",
    "age": "25"
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "36",
    "name": "name",
    "date": "0000-00-00",
    "age": "25"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "37",
    "name": "myname",
    "date": "0000-00-00",
    "age": "25"
  },
  "average_age": 25,
  "count": 3
}
```

How do I get the count of values other than average_age and count
that is for the given json object i want to get 3 as length in jQuery

Comment: Why not just access the `count` property?

Comment: This "average_age":25,"count":3 is not valid JSON. it must be "average_age":"25","count":"3"

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol how to use it ?

Comment: @LShetty It's perfectly valid to use number literals as JSON values. See http://www.json.org/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the appropriate solution is very specific to data structure in question, and unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @kol, you are right, my bad :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I have got the answer

```
Object.keys(result).length // returns 5
```

**UPDATE**

From the comment this does not work on IE 7 and 8

Comment: As it's important to my case: just note that this does not work IE8 and lower as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/14379528/731782

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
var count = 0;
while (obj[count]) {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To "get the count of values other than `average_age` and `count`", you can do something like this:

```
function getCount(obj) {
    var count = 0,
        prop;

    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== "average_age" && prop !== "count") {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

var str = '{"0":{"id":"35","name":"Ahamed shajeer","date":"2014-03-03","age":"25"},"1":{"id":"36","name":"Meshajeer","date":"0000-00-00","age":"25"},"2":{"id":"37","name":"Iam shajeer","date":"0000-00-00","age":"25"},"average_age":25,"count":3}',
    obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.clear;
console.log(getCount(obj));
```

Result:

```
3
```

You don't need jQuery. Anyway, why don't you want to use the `count` field directly?

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me:

var jsonObject= JSON.stringify(response);
var count = JSON.parse(jsonObject).length;